# How do I downgrade my ethers.js version from 5.7.2 to 5.6.1?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nft, ethers.js, ether

I'm building an NFT Marketplace demo. Whenever I try to click on 'Create an NFT' button, an Unhandled

```
Runtime Error pops up - 

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length').
Call Stack
toUtf8Bytes
node_modules\@ethersproject\strings\lib.esm\utf8.js (176:20)
StringCoder.encode
node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib.esm\coders\string.js (12:47)
eval
node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib.esm\coders\array.js (49:0)
Array.forEach
<anonymous>
pack
node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib.esm\coders\array.js (43:0)
TupleCoder.encode
node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib.esm\coders\tuple.js (51:19)
AbiCoder.encode
node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib.esm\abi-coder.js (86:0)
Interface._encodeParams
node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib.esm\interface.js (253:0)
Interface.encodeFunctionData
node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\lib.esm\interface.js (295:0)
eval
node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib.esm\index.js (125:0)
Generator.next
<anonymous>
fulfilled
node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib.esm\index.js (5:42)
```

`
I tried to resolve it by two methods suggested online -

1. Make changes to Infura 'projectId' and 'projectSecret' in .env file and change the 'createitem' function in 'create-nft.js' as well.
2. Downgrade the ethers.js from current version to 5.6.1, as all the later versions cause problems with Hardhat. But I don't how to downgrade ethers.js and can't find a link where it is stated clearly how to do it.

Comment: You just install that specific version: `npm install ethers@5.6.1 --save`.

Comment: npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ether@5.6.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
 a package version that doesn't exist.
Can  you  help @Andy?

Comment: Hey, I tried using  `npm i ethers@5.6.1` and it worked!

Comment: still my issue is not resolving

Comment: try using yarn. Are you following Nader Dabit tutorial as well?